# Is there a way to set an initial position for the tracked object?

Tags: azure-object-anchors

Is there a way to explicitly set an initial position for the object tracker, other than just placing the bounding box around the object? I have my objects already detected but want to use AOA to improve the tracking accuracy. It would be nice if I could just initialize the tracker with the object position I already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For C++ you can set the search area as a position/rotation like this:

```
auto searchArea = ObjectSearchArea::FromLocation(coordinateSystem, float3(0, 0, 0), quaternion::identity());
```

for Unity/C# you can set the search area as a position/rotation like this:

```
var searchArea = ObjectSearchArea.FromLocation(coordinateSystem.Value, Vector3.zero.ToSystem(), Quaternion.identity.ToSystem());
```